# How do I configure log4j per deployed application in Glassfish 3?

Tags: java, web-services, logging, glassfish, log4j

I'm trying to use log4j to handle the logs for a web-service which is running under Glassfish 3. Most of the guides I've seen using log4j with Glassfish want me to mess around with Glassfish global settings, which I want to avoid as there will be more than one application deployed per instance of Glassfish.

Is there any way for me to have Glassfish execute a piece of code when my web service is deployed which will allow me to call DOMConfigurator and set up log4j using my XML file?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The answer is to place the log4j.xml file in WEB-INF/classes. In our case, it looks as if log4j remains un-configured, but logging does still actually work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. All you need to do is deploy the log4j configuration with the component you're deploying; log4j will use the locally-scoped configuration as long as it's not being referenced in a parent classloader.

Glassfish' global settings won't factor in at all in that case.

Comment: Thanks for that Joseph. I have the log4j component deployed - my issue is that I need to be able to configure it using my log4j.xml file. Log4j will currently spit out warnings that I have no appenders configured - these are in my xml file and I only wish to configure this once. I just need to know how to do this in the case of a web service. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, now I don't understand something: "the log4j component?" In my understanding, Log4J is just a library, not a separate component; configuration of the log4j services takes place on a local classloader level, so you'd just use the log4j configuration as if you were in a standalone application, in the LOCAL application.

Comment: put log4j.xml in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Apologies, that was just bad writing on my behalf. The web service currently deploys fine, but when we try to call log4j, log4j complains about its configuration. This tells me that everything is set up ok, but the log4j.xml file is not being discovered. I agree that this seems to be a class-path issue, but the problem is that we don't know where (in our Glassfish project) to place the log4j.xml file so that log4j will pick it up by default. For example, in Netbeans, I would have thought that having the log4j.xml file in the build/web directory would allow log4j to pick up the file by default.

Comment: Nope, WEB-INF/classes is the right place. If it's an EJB jar instead of a web application, it'd go in the root of the EJB jar.

Comment: Can you describe the architecture of your component more thoroughly?

Comment: It's very simple really - all it consists of is a web application which contains a web service. There is nothing special about it, and it was all pretty much generated automatically by Netbeans. In total I'd say it has about 1,000 lines of code, if that - for the entire application. We have the WS interface itself, then 2 controllers which perform all of the actual logic. The only logging we require will be done from the WS interface itself. The WS class itself is instantiated on every call - which is why we need somewhere else to configure log4j when the application is actually deployed.

Comment: No, you can use standard approaches. The webservice implementation would just have a "Logger log=LogFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());" which would load the logger from the factory - which is initialized once, on first call. It's not an expensive call, and would do what you need done.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of being able to configure the logger. This particular WS is part of a much larger system and we have to do particular things with the logs - which is why we have chosen log4j due to its flexibility. All we need is a way for log4j to automatically detect its configuration file once it is loaded. If we really have to, we can call DOMConfigurator every single time the WS is instantiated, but obviously we would like to avoid this. Keeping the config xml file in WEB-INF/classes doesn't seem to work for us.

Comment: You would only have to configure the logfactory *once*. If you have to do it at context load, do so. If not, do it when you DO need to.

Comment: TomFromThePool, with all due respect, you're trying to figure out a new kind of screwdriver to use on a standard screw head. What you're asking for is very normal and *very* common, so either there's a requirement you're not describing, or you're misunderstanding how the system works.

Incidentally, log4j isn't the best choice: slf4j probably is, or logback. Even Log4J's author moved on, having written commons-logging, slf4j, *and* logback since log4j was designed.

Comment: Opinions about log4j's suitability aside - we are _trying_ to configure the logger only once. That is the problem - we have an XML file from which we need to read the configuration for the logger, and we need to know where this file should go in order for us to be able to deploy the web-service with no fuss. If we _need_ to manually call DOMConfigurator, we can do this, but it seems reasonable to expect log4j to be able to pick up the default configuration file. All we need to know is where this configuration file should reside.

Comment: Again, the classpath is all you need: WEB-INF/classes, as someone else suggested.

Comment: Hi Joseph, apologies but it seems like you and matt b were right. It appears that we are able to actually log using our default configuration as expected, but for some reason if we try to query the logger, it simply **appears** as if it has no appenders and is un-configured. We're trying to work out where the problem is that causes this. Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: It seems like the 'meat' of this answer is actually in the comments, not the answer.  please consider editing the answer to put the complete, detailed answer in the answer.